# Smart navigation

Tags: .net

What is smart navigation in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

SmartNavigation is a property of the Page class in System.Web.UI. When a request comes in to Internet Explorer 5.5 or higher and SmartNavigation is turned on (set to true), the following actions are performed:

- The flash caused by navigation is eliminated
- The scroll position is persisted when moving from page to page
- Element focus is persisted between navigations
- Only the last page state in the browser's history is retained

Here is a [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163735.aspx) about it.

*Warning* It doesn't work on other browser than IE. Should not be used for public website.

Comment: Well, with IE when you go back, the speed is pretty fast. Otherwise, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

A feature of ASP.NET that allows a web page to do a postback and display new content without flickering or skipping back to the top of the page.
I don't see that it has much place now that AJAX exists.